# cx_Oracle: ImportError: DLL load failed: This application has failed

Tags: python, dll, oracle11g, cx-oracle

Here's what I did:

1. I'm on Windows XP SP3
2. I already had Python 2.7.1 installed.
3. I downloaded `instantclient-basic-nt-11.2.0.3.0.zip`, unzipped it, and put it in `C:\Program Files\Oracle\instantclient_11_2`.
4. I added this path to the Windows `Path` environment variable.
5. I created a new environment variable `ORACLE_HOME` holding this path as its value.
6. I installed `cx_Oracle-5.1.2-11g.win32-py2.7.msi`.

And on running `import cx_Oracle` all I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module> 
ImportError: DLL load failed: This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

I obviously uninstalled / reinstalled cx_Oracle a couple of times but really nothing seems to help. Could anyone please provide a clue how to fix this?

**UPDATE**

I ran Dependency Walker and it comes up with a lot of trouble. However, the first missing .dll (msvcr80.dll) is actually **present** in `C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC80.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.91_x-ww_0de56c07`.

[image]

Answer (score 17):

OK, what finally solved the problem (not sure whether all steps are necessary and no idea why exactly this and only this worked so far):

- Download and unzip **version 12** from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html).
- Add "**ORACLE_HOME**" as a Windows environment variable and set its value to **...\instantclient_12_1**, (not its containing folder!).
- Add this same path to the "**Path**" environment variable.
- Only now install [cx_Oracle](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I didn't need to add ORACLE_HOME.  I extracted the instant client to c:\Python and then added C:\Python27\instantclient_11_2 to the path.  Thanks Ruben!

Comment: Just to add something I have just found. It requires rebooting on Windows!

Comment: I already had ORACLE_HOME and cx_Oracle installed but it was not in the PATH. I just added %ORACLE_HOME% to the path and it started working. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

**To help other people with the same problem:**

This error tells about 32-64 bit mismatch between some DLL while importing module. Possibilities are:

1. Different architecture of Python and cx_Oracle (less probable since  cx_Oracle installer on Windows warns you if appropriate Python was not found).
2. Different architecture of cx_Oracle libraries and oci.dll (more probable).

Keep in mind that cx_Oracle uses standart Oracle client (at OCI level), which must be installed on your machine. It searches for oci.dll in several places, including **PATH**. If it finds oci.dll of wrong version of the client, the error appears.

In case you get this error, check path list in the **PATH** environment variable. It is likely to contain path to BIN folder of wrong version of Oracle client. If you have several clients, specify in the **PATH** the appropriate one, or install the appropriate client.

**NOTE:** ORACLE_HOME does not have an effect for cx_Oracle. In my case only changing of PATH helped. I think the Ruben's solution works because of item 3 ('Add this same path to the "Path" environment variable').

Comment: I agree, no need for **ORACLE_HOME** in my case either. My set up is 64-bit Win, 64-bit Python 3.4 ( _via Anaconda_ ), with cx_Oracle installed via Conda but then just dumping the extracted instantclient in an arbitrary C: drive location and adding that to the **PATH** (as others above and below have done). At that point it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

I am using python35 64 bit and oracle express on win 7 (64 bit).
I installed cx_Oracle using pip3 (`pip3 install cx_Oracle`) instead of downloading the installer from pypi.

I faced the same problem.

I solved it by following above guidelines, but instead of 32 bit client, I downloaded the 64 bit version of the instant client (instantclient-basic-windows.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip)  from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html.

I then extracted it to c:\oraclexe. And added these environment variables

```
set ORACLE_BASE=C:\oraclexe
set ORACLE_HOME=C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server
set PATH=C:\oraclexe\instantclient_11_2;%PATH%
```

And ran my django migrate commands:
    python manage.py migrate

It worked excellent

Answer (score 3):

Easy way:

- Make sure you have installed cx-Oracle, I have `cx_Oracle-5.1.3-11g.win32-py2.7.exe`
- Download, unzip `instantclient_12_1` and move it to `C:\Python27`
- Add environment variable `C:\Python27\instantclient_12_1`
- Restart your computer

Answer (score 2):

Same `ImportError` occured for setup of:

- Windows 10 x64
- Oracle Instant Client 12_1 x64
- Python 2.7.11 x64
- cx_Oracle cx_Oracle-5.2-12c.win-amd64-py2.7

I solved it copying `msvcr100.dll` file into `<oracle_instant_client_dir>`

Answer (score 2):

Had this issue also, and it seems importing cx_Oracle (at least as of 5.1.2) will fail (with the same error) if you have any invalid/unreachable UNC paths in front of Oracle in the PATH environment variable.

Fixing the UNC path (which was unrelated to Oracle) resolved the problem.

Comment: What is a UNC path?

Comment: A UNC path is a path not including a drive letter, like \\server\sharename\

Answer (score 1):

If you're using conda as a package manager, one way to overcome the DLL issue it to install oracle-instantclient by doing a `conda install oracle-instantclient`. This fixed the dependency which I couldn't fix by manually installing Oracle's instant-client.

Answer (score 0):

As is the second time I came to this question, I feel the need to post what I did:

I'm using:

- Win 8 64 bits
- Python 2.7

I had no success installing Python and cx_Oracle **64 bits**.

It only worked when I tried 32 bits versions and followed @rob answer instructions

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with DLL load failed on my Windows machine.
installed oracle client, set variables, ran cx_Oracle-5.1.3-11g.win32-py2.7.exe file.

however when I installed cx_Oracle with easy_setup it fixed the problem.

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install.exe cx_Oracle-5.1.3-11g.win32-py2.7.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps I have followed :

1. Downloaded the smart client instantclient-basic-windows.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip
2. Extracted and copied to #your directory#\instantclient_12_1

   Above directory contains dll's
3. Append the PATH variable with #your directory#\instantclient_12_1 and created env variable ORACLE_HOME= #your directory#\instantclient_12_1
4. Download and install cx_Oracle-5.2.1-11g.win-amd64-py2.7.exe
5. Open idle type import cx_Oracle

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question or contribute to the discussion.

Comment: @sshale: Yes it does. It helps to see the correct order and steps taken to get cx_Oracle installed.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Anaconda on Windows try:

```
conda install cx_oracle
```

on your cmd

-> this

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I had this problem today and none of the solutions worked. I figure this could work for others with the same problem as of now.

Python version : 2.7.15 (64 bits)
cx_Oracle version : 6.4.1
Oracle Instant Client : 18.3

I kept getting the following error even though I followed evry steps in the correct order :

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Oracle Client library cannot be loaded

I solved it by downgrading my Oracle Instant Client version to 12.1

Comment: Please add more details about the environment and/or open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues) so we can understand why this was necessary.