# Python Importing cx_Oracle ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I have installed cx_Oracle for the connection of Oracle in Django Framewrok(Python).
I have installed the following:

1. Python 3.4.1 (32 bit)
2. cx_Oracle-5.1.2-11g.win32-py3.3  (32 bit)
3. Oracle 11.2.0.2 Server (32 bit)

I set the Environment variable ORACLE_HOME = "C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin"(My Path)

In command Prompt I wrote the following Lines:

```
   Python
   import cx_Oracle
```

But It shows an ImportError :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stdin", line 1, in module
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: I am not sure if it is relevant, you used py3.4.1 but the cx_oracle version is for py3.3, shouldn't you be using cx_oraclc for py3.4?

Comment: cx_oracle for py3.4 has not yet released

Comment: few days back i too got the same issue .what i did is unistalled all the packages and python  and reinstalled it. magically it worked

Comment: possible duplicate of [cx\_Oracle: ImportError: DLL load failed: This application has failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20159566/cx-oracle-importerror-dll-load-failed-this-application-has-failed)