# cx_Oracle on Python2 and Python3 (Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-oracle

I have been using Python 2.7 so far on my Windows 10 machine.
Now I need to migrate towards Python3.6, but I need to run both versions in parallel for quite a while until all old scripts have been converted to Python3. From the Python3 documentation, I gather that this should be possible.

I have installed both versions, which seems to have worked, and Hello World etc. works fine on both.

Now, one of the modules I routinely work with is cx_Oracle, and even though I have installed it for Python3, it does not seem to work. (I have installed both Python and cx_Oracle from .exe installers, both are 32 bit versions, just like the old Python2.7 (under which cx_Oracle works just fine).

```
import cx_Oracle
```

gives me

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: Procedure not found
```

I have adjusted PATH to contain both Python27 and Python3, and I have rebooted.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this? Does the Python3 version need its own Oracle Instant Client or something?

**Edit:**
I have installed cx_Oracle cx_Oracle-6.0b1-cp36-cp36m-win32 using pip, without errors, and rebooted again.

Now cx_Oracle works from within Eclipse PyDev but when I call the same script from IDLE, I get ''ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Oracle''' ???

Comment: you need oracle client for python3 which should be greater than 6 and oracle 11i or greater to use it

Comment: Have you set the `ORACLE_HOME ` environment variable to point to your InstantClient folder? You'll also need to add the InstantClient folder to your `PATH`env variable. Make sure it's the first folder. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24889483/3165737) as well.

Comment: Why does this need to be specified for Python3 but not for Python2?

Comment: I have set these, and it still doesn't work. (Instant Client version 11.2, cx_Oracle version 5.3.12)